# Is there a shorter syntax for returning the first element of an array or null?

Tags: javascript

I find this syntax lengthy. Is there a shorter syntax like inspiring from null coalescing ?

```
let a = [];
console.log(a.length>0?a[0]:null);
```

Comment: Why not literally null coalescing? `a[0] ?? null`

Comment: If not using named key value pairs then try above but if you are suppose using named key value pairs then above code is the way to go for eg:
`a['hello']='no'`
[hello: 'no']
a.push(2)
[2,'hello':'no']

Comment: @innocent I wouldn't recommend adding random keys to an array.

Comment: @VLAZ me 2 but the above takes care of all cases just incase :)

Answer (score 2):

Better way using
[Optional_chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

> The optional chaining operator (?.) enables you to read the value of a property located deep within a chain of connected objects without having to check that each reference in the chain is valid.

[Nullish_coalescing_operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator)

> The nullish coalescing operator (??) is a logical operator that returns its right-hand side operand when its left-hand side operand is null or undefined, and otherwise returns its left-hand side operand.

```js
let a = [];
a.push("foo");
// long
console.log(a.length>0 ? a[0] : null);
// short
console.log(a[0] ?? null)
```

Comment: Why the `?.` - `a` is not nullish.

Comment: Optional_chaining see an update!

Comment: I know what optional chaining is. I'm asking why use it here at all when it *very clearly* is not needed.

Comment: Had no idea about optional chaining or the nullish operator, thanks!!

Comment: Glad you know it now @SpencerMay

Comment: But @VLAZ could you where `?.` needed if it's not for checking undefined and null when accessing array elements or objects properties?

Comment: `?.` is only optionally chaing if the part ***before*** it is not `null` or `undefined`. In `a?.[0]` the variable `a` is *guaranteed* to not be `null` or `undefined`. The initial check `a.length>0 ? a[0] : null` relies on it, otherwise there would be an error with `a.length`. The expression `a[0]` is thus guaranteed to have ***exactly*** the same result as `a?.[0]` thus no null-garding is necessary. Both expressions can return `null` or `undefined`, however, that's handled by the nullish coalescing operator. The optional chaining has no impact here at all.